# Re-order ENUM in SQL databalse

Tags: mysql, sql, enums

I have a database which is already online, full of data.

I want to do requests "ORDER BY" an ENUM field. I understood that the data is ordered in the same order as I registered the possible enum values in my table (when i declared it).

My question is : I want to change that order. Is there a possible way to change the order of my enum values in the table without deleting them (because this would alter the data which is already in the table)?

Thank you!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres?

Comment: (1)  You should tag your question with your database.  (2) What a good reason to use a reference table with foreign key relationships rather than enums.

Comment: Stored data does not have a guaranteed order (see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql for more).  One approach would be to add a new column to your table.  You can then store the order you'd like the records returned in.